# Block Nginx for everyone except office IP

Tags: nginx

Is it possible to configure nginx so that ALL websites are only accessible from the office IP address only?

This is a development server that, on some sites (too many to block one by one) accidentaly has some views and activity going and I want to block everyones' access except the people in the office which come from the office IP.

Is there any way to that?

Comment: How you define 'office ip'?

Comment: A dynamic ip that very rarely changes

Comment: So how you want to declare ip that 'rarely changes' in nginx or firewall?

Comment: By following its pattern, up until now isp only has changed the last segment of the ip, I was considering an ip range for it.

Comment: So why don't you want to stick with iptables?

Comment: I didn't say I didn't, but at the time of asking, that didn't even came to mind, yet I don't know If ip tables is already installed on the server

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Why it needs firewall? `allow/deny` directives can be used not only in `location` sections, but in `http` section too.

```
http {
  allow 192.168.1.10; # office ip
  deny all;

  server {
    server_name acme1.com;
    # ...
  }

  server {
    server_name acme2.com;
    # ...
  }

}
```

Comment: I still have to check, but if the config uses a catch all server style configuration I can use the allow directive on the http block in the "main configuration file" and do the same as iptables?

Comment: @ddrjm yes, of course

Answer (score 1):

Sounds more like a work for a firewall. Assuming you are running Linux you could use iptables.

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --src source_address --dport destination_port -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport destination_port -j DROP
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use iptables to block port 80 for all IPs except your office.

Comment: That can't be done since our ip is dynamic and we can't afford being locked out of that server.

Comment: it's basically doing the same as you want. you'll still have ssh access, ftp access etc. even if your ip changes, you just blocking web access for everyone else.

Comment: I might consider this but blocking every port except port 80 and 22 both inbound and outbound, or is that a bit extreme? Also, can you point me to a tutorial or something regarding ip tables configuration?

Comment: I'd not block anything outbound. What you can do to start is to block port 80 for anyone except your office. It would be also good for security reason to block port 22 same way but you'll be locked out when your dynamic IP changes. So ultimately it will be this way:
1. Block everything except for established connections
2. Allow port 22 for anyone
3. Allow port 80 just for your office

Here's a good tutorial for CentOS but you can find other OS there as well https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-setup-a-basic-ip-tables-configuration-on-centos-6

Answer (score 0):

As mentionned, `iptables` is an option.

As an alternative you can use the Nginx `ngx_http_access_module` to restrict access.

E.g assuming your office network is `192.168.1.0/24` :

```
location / {
    allow 192.168.1.0/24; # Office network
    deny  all;
    ...
    ...
}
```

Or

```
location / {
    allow 192.168.1.10; # James
    allow 192.168.1.11; # John
    deny  all;
    ...
    ...
}
```

Note : using this approach, users with IPs not allowed will get a `403`, not a "site unreachable".

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_access_module.html